# using open telemetry UI components (jaeger/zipkin) with legacy storage/formats

Tags: open-telemetry

We have a large set of deployed applications that implement our own form of instrumentalization, which is by chance very **similar to the open-telemetry** standard.

- using NLog we trace usage, activity, exceptions and metrics
- our traces include logger context, time fields, duration (span) and transaction-id. we do not trace parent-id.
- all that massive payload is stored on **ElasticSearch**

We use different viewers and Kibana to display the log entries, but I'd like to view them as trees and full spans. For that purpose I want to use **Jaeger/Zipkin front ends** as a **display layer** (with its search components).

Is it possible to do that?
Do those UIs offer a way to configure and map both our **field names to the open-telemetry standard** and our **ElasticSearch indices as sources**?